# can't send data file to backend reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

hi guys i try to send data input file from react js to nodejs , but i got undefined

here the client

```
const [myFile, setmyFile] = useState("");

  const onFileUpload = () => {
    try {
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append("file", myFile);
      Axios.post(url + "uploads", data).then((res) => {
        console.log(res.statusText);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error while uploading image to server", error);
    }
  };

<div>
        <h1>GeeksforGeeks</h1>
        <h3>File Upload using React!</h3>
        <div>
          <input
            type="file"
            onChange={(event) => {
              setmyFile(event.target.files[0]);
            }}
          />
          <button onClick={onFileUpload}>Upload!</button>
        </div>
        {/* {fileData()} */}
      </div>
```

here the server

```
app.post("/uploads", async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.file);
});
```

can someone help me :D

Comment: I suggest you use a package like multer to handle files in the server.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Answer (score 1):

Use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) npm

```
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({
  dest: 'uploads/'
})

app.post("/uploads", upload.single('file'), async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.file);
});
```